# Fuzzy string-matching that can "skip"? e.g. "i am (.*)." has 0 distance to "I am here."

Tags: regex, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I'm writing a Python chatbot. No matter what the technique is(Levenshtein, LCS, regex, etc.), I want a pattern like `My name is [ A ].` smart enough to match strings like:

```
My name is Tslmy.              #Distance should = 0, and groupdict()['a'] outputs "Tslmy"
My name is Tesla Tahomana.     #Distance should = 0(!), and groupdict()['a'] outputs "Tesla Tahomana"
my  naem ist tslmy .           #With a little typo, the distance = 5, and groupdict()['a'] outputs "tslmy "
```

Allow me to use `groupdict()['a']` to refer to what the `[ A ]` thing (actually `(?P<identifier>match)`) has captured, please.

- In other way, I'm looking for a "Levenshtein" with omits/skippings/blanks/neglects, and **pick out what has been skipped** as well.
- In another way, I'm looking for a fuzzy(a.k.a. approximate) regex that can be less strict with the pattern, still provides the good old **`groupdict()`**, as well as a **"fuzziness" value** (or "edit distance", required to determine "the best matched pattern to the string" later).
  This is the preferred solution, since it provides "sufficient" `groupdict()` if well managed.
  However, The TRE library and the REGEX library, which is found to be the closest solution, don't seem to provide a "fuzziness" value. If this can be solved, then so much the better!

Is that possible? Thanks for paying attention.

**Update:**

I decided to use the powerful [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module in the end, but still unable to get the "fuzziness value".

Since the question on *this* page is theoratically solved, appending too further will be dishonorable. So I put forward [another question about this new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023862/python-regex-module-fuzziness-value), and hopes you could solve it!

Comment: You may consider using Damerau–Levenshtein rather than plain Levenshtein as it will consider “naem” to have a distance of 1 from “name” rather than 2, not that it helps you with your problem.

Comment: Yes, I am using DL in production. To simplify the question, I only referred to it as a normal Levenshtein. What's more, in fact, I don't really care about _what_ the fuzzy algrithm is. Thank you for your reminders, as they will delight those who have not enjoyed DL~!      @icktoofay

Comment: BTW, you probably want your final `.` to be escaped; `[.]` or `\.` -- otherwise, it matches any character, rather than only itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a RegEx for the basic match:

```
r"My name is (\w+){1,2}."
```

And then use the [TRE](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/) library to allow for variations.

Comment: Errrrr... Allow me to ask how can I use this library in my Python code? The `python\setup.py.in` seems to need `win32\Release\tre.dll` which is nonexistent.

Comment: Update: After some Googling, I found [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) to be a easlier alternative... maybe?

Comment: Well, I am choosing this answer for now. I decided to use the powerful [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module in the end, but still unable to get the "fuzziness value".        Since the question on _this_ page is theoratically solved, appending too further will be dishonorable. So I put forward [another question about this new issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023862/python-regex-module-fuzziness-value), and hopes you could solve it!

Answer (score 0):

### DAT REGEX O_O

> (?i)(?:(?:my|ym).?|.?(?:my|ym))\s+(?:.?(?:..me|n..e|na..)|(?:..me|n..e|na..).?)\s+(?:(?:is|si).?|.?(?:is|si))\s+(\w[\w\s]*)\s*

**Let's split it up:**

- `(?i)` : set the `i` modifier to match case insensitive
- `(?:(?:my|ym).?|.?(?:my|ym))` : this will match `my, ym, My, Ym, may, amy etc...`
- `\s+` : match white space one or more times
- `(?:.?(?:..am|n..e|na..)|(?:..am|n..e|na..).?)` : match `name, naao, tame, lame, n99e, names, Naats etc...`
- `\s+` : match white space one or more times
- `(?:(?:is|si).?|.?(?:is|si))` : Match `is, si, ist, sit, siR etc...`
- `\s+` : match white space one or more times
- `(\w[\w\s]*)` : match words and spaces one or more times and group it (it must start with a word `\w`)
- `\s*` : match white spaces zero or more times

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/tF3jK9)</kbd>

Comment: Man, you are killing me!~ :)

Comment: Hehe~ You can improve it by using `[a-z]` instead of `\w` depending on your needs, since `\w` will also match `_` and digits

Comment: Sorry, there's tons of such patterns to match, so, being extremely lazy, I can't afford to manage it. BTW, it mush took you some time to compose this pattern, right?

Comment: @tslmy Hmmm didn't really mention the time, but I would think about 10mn. I think it would depend on how fluent you're in regex, I'm writing regex here on SO almost every day xD. BTW you gave me a nice idea to write something that automates the process for writing this regex. Something in PHP to generate a regex like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17010983) under  "Breaking the laws of regex".

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I just finished high school 3 days before and am very much a freshman in every means. The regex, to tell you the truth, takes me days to study -- harder than Chemistry~! Seems you are doing great work in automating regex generation. Thank you again!

Comment: @tslmy It's easier than you think, I learned it here on SO btw. Reading some tutorials on the web, and honing my skills by answering questions, and ofcourse learning from other answers.

Comment: You can also use tools like [this guy](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) that make writing reliable regexes much less painful