# Python "regex" module: Fuzziness value

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-comparison, pypi-regex

I'm using the "fuzzy match" functionality of the [Regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module.

How can I get the "fuzziness value" of a "match" which indicates how different the pattern is to the string, just like the "edit distance" in Levenshtein?

I thought I could get the value in the Match object, but it's not there. The official docs said nothing about it, neither.

e.g.:

```
regex.match('(?:foo){e}','for')
```

`a.captures()` tells me that the word "for" is matched, but I'd like to know the fuzziness value, which should be `1` in this case.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: It's certainly not ideal, but if all else fails you could try repeated attempts with `(?:foo){e<=i}` where you loop over some integer `i`. The first time you get a match, your `i` is the Levenshtein distance.

Comment: Or if you are working with a limited number of errors you could use something like `(foo)|((?:foo){e=1})|((?:foo){e=2})` and check which group matched, if first e = 0, second e = 1, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import difflib
>>> matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'foo', 'for')
>>> sum(size for start, end, size in matcher.get_matching_blocks())
2
>>> max(map(len, ('foo', 'for'))) - _
1
>>>
>>>
>>> matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'foo', 'food')
>>> sum(size for start, end, size in matcher.get_matching_blocks())
3
>>> max(map(len, ('foo', 'food'))) - _
1
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks
http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes

Comment: Errrr... This workaround is great, and difflib is good stuff, too. But I have to use the "groupdict" thing in re/regex, so, I don't think difflib is suitable for that. Thanks all the same.

Comment: I replaced the regex module with the difflib like you said, and it works like a charm! So, I wonder is this "SequenceMatcher" thing comparable to the Levenshtein algrithm?

Comment: In [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/464e8fd7300d/Lib/difflib.py), there is no mention about Levenshtein. (I didn't read throughly.)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = regex.match('(?:foo){e}','for')
a.fuzzy_counts
```

this returns a tuple (x,y,z) where:

x = number of substitutions

y = number of insertions and

z = number of deletions

But this is not always a reliable count, ie: the regex match fuzziness night not equate to the true Levinstein distance in some cases

[Python regex module fuzzy match: substitution count not as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193749/python-regex-module-fuzzy-match-substitution-count-not-as-expected)