# Regex number range for nonexistent dates

Tags: regex

I am trying to use the Ignore List in the program `Bulk Image Downloader` and the include/exclude lists use regular expressions. The program lets you search a range such as:

```
http://example.com/gallery/page[1-99].htm
```

to pull out images from pages

```
example.com/gallery/page1.htm  
example.com/gallery/page2.htm  
…  
example.com/gallery/page99.htm
```

Simple enough right? The problem occurs when searching sites that use the `"yyyymmdd"` format instead of using the simple `"page#"` format.

I came up with this

```
example.com/[yyyy0101-yyyy1231].html
```

with whatever year I am downloading from in place `yyyy` to pull all the appropriate pages and I just go through and delete the chaff. The problem is instead of searching through 365 pages it searches
1131 and takes about 12 times as long to search because it searches all those dates that don't exist and tries pages that don't respond 4 times.

I then found a workaround for this using:

```
example.com/images/[yyyy0101-yyyy1231].png
```

because some of the sites I'm downloading from have their images all in one place. But I ran into the same problem but in reverse. The image search ends nigh instantly, but with all the dates that don't exist having false images (the program gives them placeholders) that take forever to go through while downloading instead of while searching.

So I tried to write a regular expression for the exclude list, which would automatically get rid of anything found in nonexistent date ranges. I even looked up how many days are in each month and made sure to leave in Feb 29 for leap years. Behold.

```
[0132-0200]
[0230-0300]
[0332-0400]
[0431-0500]
[0532-0600]
[0631-0700]
[0732-0800]
[0832-0900]
[0931-1000]
[1032-1100]
[1131-1200]
```

Turns out regular expressions do not work the way the program itself does. I tried looking it up and quite frankly didn't understand it very well.

So how exactly should this look?

I don't need whatever the exclude regular expression is, in it because it is going into the Ignore List. Although it might be useful to someone else.

*Edit*

*Start*

I want the program to only display pictures from real dates on photos by isolating out mmdd dates that are invalid/nonexistent. 
I do not know what flavor of Regex is used by the program. From their site:

> The following characters have special meanings when used in regular
>   expressions and must be prefixed by a backslash (`\`) if you wish to use
>   them as literals in your regular expression.
>
> `[, \, ^, $, ., |, ?, *, +, (, ), /`
>
> ^ = start of line $ = end of line . = match any character \x = use
>   literal character x
>
> For a detailed explanation of regular expressions please visit
>   http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

*End*

*Edit*

Comment: Consider avoiding regex for dates.  What if the date in question belongs to `September 1752`.

Comment: Your question is unclear, well your situation is unclear. What is most important in a regex question **1)** Language or regex flavor **2)** expected input **3)** expected output. You may be interested in [my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17010983/) which shows that it's possible to match dates, but not practical at all.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what Bulk Image Downloader uses as a regex engine, you might try:

```
example.com/[201301-201312](0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).html
```

This should let you select valid months for the year you select

```
[201301-201312]
```

Then the date can be a 01 - 09

```
0[1-9]
```

10-29

[1-2][0-9]

or 30,31

```
3[0-1]
```

Combine the date parts into a group with the or operator

```
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])
```

put it all together as above, and it may work for an entire year.  Again depending on precisely which regular expression engine they've decided to use.

Comment: Since this is core regex functionality with nothing tricky it will work the same way in any regex engine. (Conversely, if it does not work, it is not being interpreted as a regex/instead as something else.)