# Matching general integer ranges with re.compile()

Tags: python, regex

How do I target integer ranges with `re.compile()` where the limits of the range are **two general integers** `a` and `b`?

For example, say I want to target strings like:

```
foo_bar_8
foo_bar_12
```

i.e. the number at the end **is within** the range `8-14` (**`a=8`**, **`b=14`**). Note that `a` and `b`are  two integers **with a possibly different number of digits**.

but not strings like:

```
foo_bar_15
foo_bar_4
foo_bar_20
```

(the number at the end is **not** within the range `8-14`)

More generally, say I have two  integers, `a` and `b`, where the number of digits of `a` and `b` may be different. How do I encode such a generic range in a regex in Python?

Comment: The scalable solution is to capture the numbers in a group and filter out the matches you don't want in a second step.

Comment: The most generic but not efficient way is to use [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html) and implode it using `|` which will give you a pattern that will match all the ints between `a` and `b`. Honestly, I won't even try it otherwise you might end up with a huge regex like [this](http://codepad.org/j1rVHdX1) [...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974342/date-range-validation-in-biztalk-edi-schema/17010983#17010983)

Comment: I think you're over complicating things by trying to match the range in regex. I would just match the pattern and filter the result.

Comment: In the rare-but-not-unprecedent case where a and b are large but the range of valid numbers is even larger (e.g., you want the numbers from 7890-12345 out of 5000000), it may be worth doing _part_ of the filtering in the regexp (only match 4-5 digit numbers, not all numbers) and the rest in a second step. But otherwise, just do what @roippi said.

Answer (score 5):

Regexps work on strings, period.  They have no knowledge of what a string of characters may *mean* to you.

It's sometimes possible to use `re.sub()` to supply meaning, though, because `sub()` is passed a function, which can implement any meaning you can program.  For example,

```
import re
def matcher(m):
    digits = m.group()
    print "matched", repr(digits), "at", m.span()
    if 8 <= int(digits) <= 14:
        print "OK!"
    else:
        print "rejected"
    return digits  # no change

s = "foo_bar_8 foo_bar_12 foo_bar_15 foo_bar_4 foo_bar_20"
re.sub("\d+", matcher, s)
```

prints:

```
matched '8' at (8, 9)
OK!
matched '12' at (18, 20)
OK!
matched '15' at (29, 31)
rejected
matched '4' at (40, 41)
rejected
matched '20' at (50, 52)
rejected
```

Depending on exactly what you want to do, this may be very easy - or very strained ;-)

Comment: This is really just a trick to cram roippi's "second step" into a function that happens to come from the `re` module; you're still searching for digits with a regexp, then post-filtering with a Python function that understands the meaning. But it _is_ a nice way to organize the code for this example.

Comment: @abarnert, it's more than *just* that. For example, I've used this trick in cases where the substitution function raises an exception if conditions aren't met. Of course that can be unboundedly faster than *post*-processing - this trick runs *during* processing.

Comment: I didn't think about the ability to raise. You're right, that gives you a way to bail out early without having to rewrite all your code around `finditer`. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following expression:

```
(?:[89]|1[01234])$
```

`[89]` matches `8` or `9`, `1[01234]` matches a `1` followed by `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`.

`$` matches the end of string.

Comment: But how would you do this generally? In other words, can you write a function that takes `a` and `b` arguments and creates the appropriate regexp?

Comment: @abarnert This question has been asked before and there is no clear or simple solution the least. Do this in real code instead of regex.

Comment: If there is no clear or simple solution for the OP's question, then say that, and close the question; don't write an answer that works for his first example and implies his question is solvable when it isn't.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry, I didn't notice that he added more requests in his question because as you can see he edited the question.

Comment: The [first version of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19735876/1) made it even _more_ obvious that this example was just an example.